# How to count and sum the number of occurences of a type string from a struct?

Tags: go

First the poor code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type rocketship struct {
    passengers     string
    gear           string

func mapper(separators map[string]string) rocketship {
    maps := rocketship{
        passengers:          separators["passengers"],
        gear:                separators["gear"],
    }
    return maps
}

func main() {

// How to pull the string
for _, passer := range passengers {
// count each passenger
sum = passer++
if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("No passengers coming today", err)
        return
          }
   fmt.Println("There are", sum, "passengers onboard today")
}
```

What are the steps here?

1. Pull a long name out of a struct (if a passenger is on the ship), can be "John Fitzgerald Kennedy" or "J.F.K" or "JFK".
2. Add this passenger in the tally
3. Continue till all passengers are counted
4. Sum the passengers and print how many there were.

The issue:

- How can a string from a struct be converted to one occurrence?
- How can the occurrences be summed together to be printed?

The final print could be "There are 6 passengers onboard today"

Comment: So all the passenger names are in one single string? how are they separated? Can you post a sample of how your struct might look like? and what do you mean by `range passengers`?

Comment: also, why not use a list instead of a string?

Comment: Navid, I added the mapper, and Praveen I'm not golang skilled, so this is my way.

Comment: I still can't understand it and there is no example of how the data looks like. if you have a separator in the text like "-", you can use `strings.split(passengersString, "-")` and then the `len()` of the result will be passengers count. But I think the passenger field in your struct should be a `[]string` which is the appropriate data type for a list of names. But still I don't know how your data looks like so I might be wrong.

Comment: Nobody can answer the question:


    How can a string from a struct be converted to one occurrence?
    How can the occurrences be summed together to be printed?